# Can't increment Cassandra counter through Datastax-PHP library

Tags: java, php, cassandra, datastax

I have the following counter column family:

```
CREATE TABLE subscription_counter (
    subscription_id timeuuid,
    amount counter,
    PRIMARY KEY(subscription_id)
);
```

When in cqlsh and run the following query, it works as intended and amount is incremented by 1.

```
UPDATE subscription_counter SET amount = amount + 1 WHERE subscription_id = 840e5f80-2fc7-11e5-9597-a1ae67be6e20
```

However from the Datastax-PHP library (http://datastax.github.io/php-driver/), the following query throws an Exception.

```
$statement = $session->prepare("UPDATE subscription_counter SET amount = amount + ? WHERE subscription_id = ?");
$result = $session->execute($statement, new Cassandra\ExecutionOptions(array(
    'arguments' => array(1, $subscription_id)
)));
```

Exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Cassandra\Exception\InvalidQueryException' with message 'Expected 8 or 0 byte long (4)' in /var/www/vhosts/cassandra_test/v4import.php:193
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/cassandra_test/v4import.php(193): Cassandra\DefaultSession->execute(Object(Cassandra\PreparedStatement), Object(Cassandra\ExecutionOptions))
#1 /var/www/vhosts/cassandra_test/v4import.php(116): processUser(Object(Cassandra\DefaultSession), 'stuart.armstron...', 'stu', 'armstrong', Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/cassandra_test/v4import.php on line 193
```

---

php -v

```
PHP 5.6.11 (cli) (built: Jul 12 2015 20:21:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

java -version

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.4.1.el6_5-x86_64 u51-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

I have tried casting 1 as a float but that does not work as intended and produces huge numbers that don't make sense. I have tried google, but can only find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708321/reading-an-8-byte-integer-in-php-bitcoin) stackoverflow question on how to unpack an 8 byte int, but I can't see how to create one from that.

Has anyone used counters from this library before? Could this be a php config issue?

I am using the library correctly as far as I know as all other queries seem to be working fine.

Please let me know if I can provide any more useful info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out Cassandra provides a Bigint object, and when using that it works.

```
$int = new Cassandra\Bigint('1');
$statement = $session->prepare("UPDATE subscription_counter SET amount = amount + ? WHERE subscription_id = ?");
$result = $session->execute($statement, new Cassandra\ExecutionOptions(array(
        'arguments' => array($int, $subscription_id)
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

For a java client, you would use a long primitive type to map to the CQL counter type.  For example, here is an accessor query (Datastax java client) that updates a counter:

```
@Accessor
public interface MyCountersAccessor {

    @Query("UPDATE my_counters SET count = count + :increment WHERE key = :key")
    ResultSet incrementCount(@Param("key") String key, @Param("increment") long increment);
}
```